# How to use sed to substitute current date?

Tags: bash, scripts, calendar, sed

How do I use `sed` to substitute date by a word. I tried doing this:

```
tmp=`date +%d`
echo $tmp
if [ $tmp -lt 10 ]
then
        pat="d"
        echo $pat
else
        pat="dd"
        echo $pat
fi
cal | sed "s/$tmp/$pat/"
```

And the output is like so:

```
robin@robin-VirtualBox:~/lx$ bash p13.sh
27
dd
     April 2014       
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
27 28 29 30
```

**Edit:**

I want the date `27` to change into `dd`, like in here:

```
     April 2014       
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
dd 28 29 30
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't finish to understand what are you trying to achieve. How should the output be like?

Comment: @Lucio Hello, I have edited my question. Please have a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: You're right, the script works for anything but `27` specifically, weird. I'm assuming there is some issue with the current day.

Comment: Yes... Its working with other dates! LOL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use `-h` when using `cal`

**Why?**

The `cal` command prints the current day with special characters ("highlighting"?). I found out this saving it to a file and using `nano` (*not* `cat`) to read it:

```
$ cal >> out
$ nano out
```

Now you will see the following:

```
     Abril 2014
do lu ma mi ju vi sá
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
_^H2_^H7 28 29 30
```

Beside Spanish (sorry) 27 is not with simple characters.

Now if you use `-h` this is solved:

```
$ cal -h >> out2
$ nano out2
```

Your output should be like this so you can parse it without problems:

```
     Abril 2014
do lu ma mi ju vi sá
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30
```

**Solution**

In your script replace `cal | sed "s/$tmp/$pat/"` with `cal -h | sed "s/$tmp/$pat/"`

---

*Source: http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?cal+1+NetBSD-current*

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you cannot parse [the output of BSD cal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11081/41104) for the current day. This is because it's highlighted. If you turn off highlighting with the `-h` switch, it will work:

```
➜  ~  cal -h | sed "s/$tmp/$pat/"
     Abril 2014       
do lu ma mi ju vi sá  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
dd 28 29 30
```

To identify the output of cal, check the strace:

```
strace cal
[...] # tons of lines here
write(1, "       1  2  3  4  5  \n", 23       1  2  3  4  5  
) = 23
write(1, " 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  \n", 23 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
) = 23
write(1, "13 14 15 16 17 18 19  \n", 2313 14 15 16 17 18 19  
) = 23
write(1, "20 21 22 23 24 25 26  \n", 2320 21 22 23 24 25 26  
) = 23
write(1, "\33[7m27\33[27m 28 29 30           \n", 3227 28 29 30           
) = 32
write(1, "                      \n", 23                      
) = 23
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```